# Can't use MySQL session variables inside the query

Tags: mysql

I have a query where I would like to use a session variable to not have to enter the number over and over to debug in MySQL Workbench.

This is the query:

```
SET @userId = 2;

SELECT
    id, 
    reply_to,
    from_id,
    to_id,
    message,
    created_time,
    is_viewed,
    IF(from_id = @userId, to_id, from_id) AS partnerId,
    IF(from_id = @userId, data->>'$.toUsername', data->>'$.fromUsername') AS partnerUsername,
    IF(from_id = @userId, data->>'$.toImage', data->>'$.fromImage') AS partnerImage
FROM message
WHERE
    (from_id = @userId OR to_id = @userId) AND
    is_active = 1
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

That query returns 0 results. But if I change it to:

```
SELECT
    id, 
    reply_to,
    from_id,
    to_id,
    message,
    created_time,
    is_viewed,
    IF(from_id = 2, to_id, from_id) AS partnerId,
    IF(from_id = 2, data->>'$.toUsername', data->>'$.fromUsername') AS partnerUsername,
    IF(from_id = 2, data->>'$.toImage', data->>'$.fromImage') AS partnerImage
FROM message
WHERE
    (from_id = 2 OR to_id = 2) AND
    is_active = 1
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

Then everything works as expected. How come it does not work the way I expect it to work?

Comment: try `select 2 into @userId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MySQL [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html):

> User variables are intended to provide data values. They cannot be used directly in an SQL statement as an identifier or as part of an identifier, such as in contexts where a table or database name is expected, or as a reserved word such as SELECT.

So you can use variable only in your application code.
For example PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT
    id, 
    reply_to,
    from_id,
    to_id,
    message,
    created_time,
    is_viewed,
    IF(from_id = :userId, to_id, from_id) AS partnerId,
    IF(from_id = :userId, data->>'$.toUsername', data->>'$.fromUsername') AS partnerUsername,
    IF(from_id = :userId, data->>'$.toImage', data->>'$.fromImage') AS partnerImage
FROM message
WHERE
    (from_id = :userId OR to_id = :userId) AND
    is_active = 1
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 50";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([':userId' => 2]);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```